# Can I align/justify confidence intervals in forest() of R metafor package

Tags: r

I have thirteen studies that I am meta-analyzing the mean difference from. Is there a way to justify or align the confidence intervals so that the parentheses are all lined up in the forest plot? Here is my current code and a picture of the resulting forest plot.

Code:

```
forest(result.mbw,  xlab=NA, 
       alim=c(-300,300), xlim=c(-700,500), digits=0)
text(c(-600),14, c("Study"))
text(c(200),14, c("Mean BW Difference (g) [95% CI]"))
```

[Forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iada9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a fixed-width font for that to happen. So, you can use `par(family="mono")` before creating the plot. Since the text width may then be wider, you may have to play around with the `xlim` argument of the `forest()` function to make it fit. Here is an example:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="MD", m1i=m1i, sd1i=sd1i, n1i=n1i, m2i=m2i, sd2i=sd2i, n2i=n2i, data=dat.normand1999)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
par(family="mono")
forest(res, xlim=c(-180,230), cex=.8)
text(-180, 11, "Study", pos=4, font=2, cex=.8)
text( 230, 11, "Mean Difference [95% CI]", pos=2, font=2, cex=.8)
```

I had to decrease `cex` a bit to make it fit better. Also, I used `pos=4` and `pos=2` when adding the text so that it also properly aligns.

If you are on Windows and want to use another font, you could do:

```
windowsFonts(Consolas=windowsFont("Consolas"))
par(family="Consolas")
```

Or use any other fixed-width font you like. Not sure how this works under MacOS or Unix/Linux.